Fluent assertions, how to compare TimeSpan
I have a test in Rx.net and Fluent Assertions:
// Arrange
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
var udpStream = new Subject<UdpReceiveResult>();

_functionMock.Setup(x => x.CreateListener<UdpReceiveResult>()!.GetStream()).Returns(udpStream);

var observer = testScheduler.CreateObserver<TimeSpan>();
var sut = new MySutClass(_functionMock.Object);

// Act
var subscription = sut.MyMethod(testScheduler).Subscribe(observer);

testScheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks);
udpStream.OnNext(new UdpReceiveResult());
testScheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9).Ticks);
udpStream.OnNext(new UdpReceiveResult());

// Assert
observer.Messages.Count.Should().Be(1);
observer.Messages[0].Value.Should().BeEquivalentTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));

In my opinion everything works fine but there is a message from console:

Expected observer.Messages[0].Value to be 4s, but found OnNext (00:00:04)

The time value is the same as I expected 4s but I think the comparison format is not valid and these two values can't compare properly.

What type is observer.Messages[0].Value? A string? If you're expecting that to be a string value with certain contents, then don't compare it directly to a date time. Compare it to a string that matches the format you expect it to be. Or if possible change your design so that you're using the proper data type to store information rather than shoving it into a string.

Thanks for your reply, I just forgot to add next Value, It should be like this observer.Messages[0].Value.Value.Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));, Now it works.

It should be like this:
observer.Messages[0].Value.Value.Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)); not
observer.Messages[0].Value.Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
